# Use Variables to Generalise a Paste query

Tags: r, variables, paste

I  have used this query to remove all items in my data set which are brought up in December 2017. I want to generalise this query by using variables instead of 'Dec' and '2017' as I will be firing this query every month.

```
q2_sql_1 <- subset(q2_sql_1,  ! paste(CAL_MONTH,YEAR,sep="_") %in% c('Dec_2017'))
```

The overall code is quite big, so it would be troublesome to find this line and edit every time. So, I  have specified 2 variables at the beginning which I will edit every month.

```
MMM <- "Dec"
YYYY <- "2017"
```

How do I use these variables in the above query?

Comment: `q2_sql_1 <- subset(q2_sql_1,  ! paste(CAL_MONTH,YEAR,sep="_") %in% paste0(MMM, "_", YYYY))`

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thank You.

Comment: @lebatsnok can you post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @lebatsnok

```
q2_sql_1 <- subset(q2_sql_1, ! paste(CAL_MONTH,YEAR,sep="_") %in% paste0(MMM, "_", YYYY))
```

Comment: I like the fact that I can now upvote my own answer if I like :)